# How Extract Data from django admin site?

Tags: database, django, django-admin, extract, django-database

I have a django admin page but i don't have the database file on my computer. How can i extract all datas from the admin page in a databse file (e.g. MyDB.sqlite) on my hard disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to go through something specifically meant to support programmatic interaction with your Django site.

Checkout [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) for an example. There are others out there, too.